# Unable to get latest pod version for BMSCore and BMSPush IBM BlueMix iOS SDK

Tags: ios, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I've followed the Bluemix Push SDK for iOS following the online documentation: 
I am trying to run a sample app - https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-samples-swift-hellopush . 
But after doing a pod update - I only get the following pods 
BMSAnalyticsAPI (1.0.1)
BMSCore (1.0.0)
BMSPush (1.0.3) .
How can I get the latest pod for the above i.e to 
BMSAnalyticsAPI (2.2.0)
BMSCore (2.3.1)
BMSPush (3.1.1)  as given their sample video -https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cOXjn3fuNG0

Comment: What is your version of CocoaPods?

Comment: I am using CocoaPods version 1.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

I am on CocoaPods version 1.1.1, and it worked successfully for me to perform a `pod update` inside the cloned repository. I recommend either installing this version, or reinstalling your current version. You must perform the `pod update` inside your project with the **Podfile**.

```
$ pod update
Update all pods
Updating local specs repositories
warning: inexact rename detection was skipped due to too many files.
warning: you may want to set your diff.renameLimit variable to at least 6318 and retry the command.

CocoaPods 1.2.1.rc.1 is available.
To update use: `sudo gem install cocoapods --pre`
[!] This is a test version we'd love you to try.

For more information, see https://blog.cocoapods.org and the CHANGELOG for this version at https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases/tag/1.2.1.rc.1

Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing BMSAnalyticsAPI (2.2.0)
Installing BMSCore (2.3.1)
Installing BMSPush (3.1.1)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project

[!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use `helloPush_Swift3.xcworkspace` for this project from now on.
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 2 dependencies from the Podfile and 3 total pods installed.
```

Doing a `pod outdated` will list all pods that have updates available too.

Comment: Hi @sachin sharma, are the correct dependency versions being installed now?